# Notification and Action center is gone

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, notification-area, action-center

[image]
It took me ages to find this setting. But as you can see in the picture, I don't have the Notification (Action) center icon on my Taskbar. And in a Settings app it appears grayed, though ON. I still am getting notifications, but if I missed to click on them, I can't review them anymore...

How can I get my Action center to appear onmy Taskbar?

Comment: did you find solution ?

Comment: I just gave up and reinstalled the OS completely. Someone mantioned malware being involved and I am not waiting for solutions then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Control Panel | Notification Area Icons. Click "Turn System
icons on or off" and make sure that the icon for Action Center is set
to On:

[image]

If your setting is grayed out, this can have to do with local / domain group policy. Another possibility: the windows security center is not running.

Take a look: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e348996a-a2a5-4af4-860e-2bdf38e64c06/greyed-out-action-center-settings?forum=winservergen

> I you want to unlock the buttons start this service: "**wscsvc**" (
>   windows security center )
>
> If you stop that service, you'll have the greyed out options but
>   everything else in the action center will work.

Comment: In windows 10 (as of 28-08-2018) the setting to edit which system icons are shown, is under Settings | Personalization | Taskbar | Notification Area.